# Como desabilitar as mensagens do XHR finished loading em produção

Tags: angular, typescript, console, webpack

Tenho um sistema desenvolvido na linguagem Angular na versão 4. O sistema que gera build da aplicação em produção é o webpack. Esta sendo utilizado como base o seguinte starter:
[angular 4 webpack starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter)
O sistema está terminado, mas tem o seguinte problema: As mensagens do XHR estão aparecendo durante as chamadas e quero que elas sejam desabilitadas em produção para esconder as chamadas que a aplicação faz.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na realidade, essa função é do console do Chrome, e não do Angular 4.

Para desabilita-la, abra o developer tools na aba console, clique nas opções (engrenagem) e desmarque a opção `LogXMLHttpRequests`.

Lembrando que, não é possível negar ao navegador a possibilidade de gravar esses logs das requests.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sim, eu entendo isso, mas eu quero que fique default desabilitado em produção sem a possibilidade de ser habilitado. Tem como?

Comment: Não é possível, o navegador precisa exibir as requisições realizadas.

Comment: Teria uma forma de criptografar o que aparece no console sobre estas requisições sei la. Queria que isso fosse escondido do usuário para evitar invasão pela url, ou coisa do tipo. seria mais uma forma de segurança.

Comment: Você pode obfuscar seus scripts de request e fazer os tratamentos de acesso às URLs pelo backend, verificando se os acessos são legítimos/autorizados. Infelizmente não posso te ajudar muito nesse tópico.

Comment: Blz. Isso me da umas ideias de como resolver. Vlww pelas dicas.

Comment: Por nada! Recomendo a leitura: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067439/obfuscating-ajax-post